# Any free plugin for Visual Studio 2012 to rename JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I know this was asked here: [Renaming variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029203/renaming-variables-in-javascript), but I'm looking for free options.

Does anyone know of a a good plugin for Visual Studio 2012 to add support for renaming of JavaScript variables? At the moment I'm having to do a find and replace which seems archaic coming from C#.

Ideas for alternative IDE's that give better JavaScript support are also welcome.

Many thanks,

Comment: It's not free, but resharper  makes JavaScript, c# and the whole of visual studio much much better and refactoring tools are great. The c # version includes JavaScript support. I turned down a contract because they wouldn't use resharper. It's that good and saves me so much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with Stanley_A's suggestion of buying http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/.  Whilst it's not free which I was hoping for, I have to say it's pretty awesome.  It solved my renaming issue but more than that it's providing incredible intellisense, goto definition now works as expected, and it already found two potential bugs which it automatically highlighted.  Clever stuff.

Comment: I "love" the downvote - the answer was from the OP, even!